# determine the catchment area from dem or hillshade

Tags: qgis, dem, hillshade, rivers

I want to determine the  catchment area of river from hillside. Is there a plugin that I can use in qgis ?

Comment: "Hillside" or "hillshade"?

Comment: I mean hillshade. I am sorry my bad in english

Comment: OK. By "hillshade" do you mean a digital elevation model (DEM) or do you mean in the usual sense of a raster with values between 0 and 255 used to produce the illusion of side-lit illumination in an image?

Comment: What do mean of"the illusion of side-lit illumination in an image'?

Comment: See, for example, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76417/srtm-nasa-hillshade-grainy-appearance.